# Binary Tree height implementation

Tags: java, height, binary-tree, implementation

This is the most common implementation for binary tree height I have found on internet

```
public int height(BinaryNode t) {
        if (t == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1 + Math.max(height(t.left), height(t.right));

        }
    }
```

But shouldn't it modified like this since it is adding an unnecessary 1 at leaf nodes

```
public int height(BinaryNode t) {
        if (t == null) {
            return 0;
        } else if (t.left == null && t.right == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1 + Math.max(height(t.left), height(t.right));
        }
    }
```

Comment: No. Just imagine the simplest case: A tree where the root is also the only leaf. What height would you get?

Comment: A tree containing a single node has a height of 0 right?

Comment: It only depends on what you call height. But as Ben said, a single node as a height of 1, one parent with two children have a height of 2, etc ...

Comment: That's indeed correct. And I didn't read your code correctly. Most common implementations have a `if(t == null) return -1` in there for exactly that case.